# Django filter queryset __in for *every* item in list

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

Let's say I have the following models

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In a view I have a list with active filters called *categories*.
I want to filter Photo objects which have all tags present in *categories*.

I tried:

```
Photo.objects.filter(tags__name__in=categories)
```

But this matches *any* item in categories, not *all* items.

So if categories would be ['holiday', 'summer'] I want Photo's with both a holiday and summer tag.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Maybe: 

    qs=Photo.objects.all();
    for category in categories: 
        qs = qs.filter(tags__name=category)

Comment: jpic is right, `Photo.objects.filter(tags__name='holiday').filter(tags__name='summer')` is the way to go. (This is same as jpic's example). Each `filter` should add more `JOIN`s to query, so you could take [annotation approach](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/5fd4c24ab067e7b6) if they are too many.

Comment: Here's the reference in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Comment: You would expect there to be a build-in function for this by Django

Comment: Photo.objects.filter(tags__name_in=['holiday','summer']) won't work?? and even to avoid unnecessary data hit, Photo.objects.filter(tags_name__in=['holiday','summer']).select_related('tag').

Answer (score 166, accepted):

**Summary:**

One option is, as suggested by jpic and sgallen in the comments, to add `.filter()` for each category. Each additional `filter` adds more joins, which should not be a problem for small set of categories.

There is the [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) [approach](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/msg/0659acee8c128f20). This query would be shorter and perhaps quicker for a large set of categories.

You also have the option of using [custom queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

---

**Some examples**

Test setup:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

In [2]: t1 = Tag.objects.create(name='holiday')
In [3]: t2 = Tag.objects.create(name='summer')
In [4]: p = Photo.objects.create()
In [5]: p.tags.add(t1)
In [6]: p.tags.add(t2)
In [7]: p.tags.all()
Out[7]: [<Tag: holiday>, <Tag: summer>]
```

### Using [chained filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) approach:

```
In [8]: Photo.objects.filter(tags=t1).filter(tags=t2)
Out[8]: [<Photo: Photo object>]
```

Resulting query:

```
In [17]: print Photo.objects.filter(tags=t1).filter(tags=t2).query
SELECT "test_photo"."id"
FROM "test_photo"
INNER JOIN "test_photo_tags" ON ("test_photo"."id" = "test_photo_tags"."photo_id")
INNER JOIN "test_photo_tags" T4 ON ("test_photo"."id" = T4."photo_id")
WHERE ("test_photo_tags"."tag_id" = 3  AND T4."tag_id" = 4 )
```

Note that each `filter` adds more `JOINS` to the query.

### Using [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) [approach](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/msg/0659acee8c128f20):

```
In [29]: from django.db.models import Count
In [30]: Photo.objects.filter(tags__in=[t1, t2]).annotate(num_tags=Count('tags')).filter(num_tags=2)
Out[30]: [<Photo: Photo object>]
```

Resulting query:

```
In [32]: print Photo.objects.filter(tags__in=[t1, t2]).annotate(num_tags=Count('tags')).filter(num_tags=2).query
SELECT "test_photo"."id", COUNT("test_photo_tags"."tag_id") AS "num_tags"
FROM "test_photo"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "test_photo_tags" ON ("test_photo"."id" = "test_photo_tags"."photo_id")
WHERE ("test_photo_tags"."tag_id" IN (3, 4))
GROUP BY "test_photo"."id", "test_photo"."id"
HAVING COUNT("test_photo_tags"."tag_id") = 2
```

### `AND`ed `Q` objects would not work:

```
In [9]: from django.db.models import Q
In [10]: Photo.objects.filter(Q(tags__name='holiday') & Q(tags__name='summer'))
Out[10]: []
In [11]: from operator import and_
In [12]: Photo.objects.filter(reduce(and_, [Q(tags__name='holiday'), Q(tags__name='summer')]))
Out[12]: []
```

Resulting query:

```
In [25]: print Photo.objects.filter(Q(tags__name='holiday') & Q(tags__name='summer')).query
SELECT "test_photo"."id"
FROM "test_photo"
INNER JOIN "test_photo_tags" ON ("test_photo"."id" = "test_photo_tags"."photo_id")
INNER JOIN "test_tag" ON ("test_photo_tags"."tag_id" = "test_tag"."id")
WHERE ("test_tag"."name" = holiday  AND "test_tag"."name" = summer )
```

Comment: Is there be a solution with a custom lookup?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-lookups/  It would cool to switch "__in" to "__all" and have it create the correct sql query.

Comment: This annotation solution seems wrong. What if there are three tags possible (lets call the additional one for `t3`, and a photo has the tags `t2` and `t3`. Then this photo will still match the given query.

Comment: @beruic I think the idea is that you would replace num_tags=2 with num_tags=len(tags); I expect the hard-coded 2 was just for example's sake.

Comment: @tbm It still would not work. `Photo.objects.filter(tags__in=tags)` matches photos that have any of the tags, not only those that has all. Some of those that only has one of the desired tags, may have exactly the amount of tags that you are looking for, and some of those that has all the desired tags, may also have additional tags.

Comment: If your Django version is 1.8 or above you could use conditional annotations. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33777815/1031534

Comment: @beruic the annotation counts only the tags returned by the query, so if (num tags returned by the query) == (num tags searched for) then the row is included; "extra" tags are not searched for, so won't be counted. I've verified this within my own app.

Comment: Is it possible that `Q` objects would work but  `OR`-ed instead ?

Comment: The annotation approach is both elegant and efficient. I would suggest placing it higher in the answer!

Answer (score 10):

Another approach that works, although PostgreSQL only, is using `django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField`:

Example copied from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#contains):

```
>>> Post.objects.create(name='First post', tags=['thoughts', 'django'])
>>> Post.objects.create(name='Second post', tags=['thoughts'])
>>> Post.objects.create(name='Third post', tags=['tutorial', 'django'])

>>> Post.objects.filter(tags__contains=['thoughts'])
<QuerySet [<Post: First post>, <Post: Second post>]>

>>> Post.objects.filter(tags__contains=['django'])
<QuerySet [<Post: First post>, <Post: Third post>]>

>>> Post.objects.filter(tags__contains=['django', 'thoughts'])
<QuerySet [<Post: First post>]>
```

`ArrayField` has some more powerful features such as [overlap](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#overlap) and [index transforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#index-transforms).

Comment: It's a powerful solution, but if you created your models before knowing about the " __in for *every* item in list" use case, you're probably not using ArrayField and will probably have to do some deep refactoring...

Answer (score 7):

This also can be done by dynamic query generation using Django ORM and some Python magic :)

```
from operator import and_
from django.db.models import Q

categories = ['holiday', 'summer']
res = Photo.filter(reduce(and_, [Q(tags__name=c) for c in categories]))
```

The idea is to generate appropriate Q objects for each category and then combine them using AND operator into one QuerySet. E.g. for your example it'd be equal to

```
res = Photo.filter(Q(tags__name='holiday') & Q(tags__name='summer'))
```

Comment: This would not work. Your query examples would not return anything for the models in question.

Comment: Thanks for correction. I thought chaining `filter` would be the same as using `and` for Q objects in one filter... My mistake.

Comment: No worries, my first thought where also Q objects.

Comment: This would we slower if you work with large tables and large data to compare to. (like 1 Million each)

Comment: This approach *should* work if you switch from `filter` to `exclude` and use a negate operator.  Like so:

`res = Photo.exclude(~reduce(and_, [Q(tags__name=c) for c in categories]))`

Comment: As it is, this answer won't return any instances (it tries to find categories whose names are  **at the same time** both "summer" and "holiday", and it will fail). Please either remove it or adjust it :-)

Answer (score 3):

I use a little function that iterates filters over a list for a given operator an a column name :

```
def exclusive_in (cls,column,operator,value_list):         
    myfilter = column + '__' + operator
    query = cls.objects
    for value in value_list:
        query=query.filter(**{myfilter:value})
    return query
```

and this function can be called like that:

```
exclusive_in(Photo,'tags__name','iexact',['holiday','summer'])
```

it also work with any class and more tags in the list; operators can be anyone like 'iexact','in','contains','ne',...

Answer (score 3):

If you struggled with this problem as i did and nothing mentioned helped you, maybe this one will solve your issue

Instead of chaining filter, in some cases it would be better just to store ids of previous filter

```
tags = [1, 2]
for tag in tags:
    ids = list(queryset.filter(tags__id=tag).values_list("id", flat=True))
    queryset = queryset.filter(id__in=ids)
```

Using this approach will help you to avoid stacking `JOIN` in SQL query:

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:**
let say
author is list of elements that need to match all item in list, so:

```
        for a in author:
            queryset = queryset.filter(authors__author_first_name=a)
                if not queryset:
                    break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for category in categories:
    query = Photo.objects.filter(tags_name=category)
```

this piece of code , filters your photos which have all the tags name coming from categories.

Answer (score -1):

If we want to do it dynamically, followed the example:

```
tag_ids = [t1.id, t2.id]
qs = Photo.objects.all()

for tag_id in tag_ids:
    qs = qs.filter(tag__id=tag_id)    

print qs
```

Comment: Cannot work as as soon as the second iteration, the queryset will be empty

Answer (score -1):

```
queryset = Photo.objects.filter(tags__name="vacaciones") | Photo.objects.filter(tags__name="verano")
```

Comment: This will return Photos that are either tagged "vacaciones" or "verano", not Photos tagged with both tags...