# Django Filter deduce ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Simple models with many to many relations on the Tag field.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()

class Species(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Now Im trying this, and as I understand, it should return a list that matches every tag_description in the tags list:

```
tag_list = request.GET.get('q').split(',')
species = Species.objects.filter(reduce(and_, [Q(tags__description=c) for c in tag_list]))
```

But its returning an empty list. It should be returning some objects.

**It works when I give it only one tag**

any idea why this is happening?

Im using it as was shown in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636836/228660

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can actually see in the comments of that question, it doesn't actually work ;)
The problem is that you will be using the same join (which means the same object) for all filters. Unless all items in `tag_list` are identical this will never work. The problem lies within the Q objects instead of full filtered queries.

```
tag_list = request.GET.get('q').split(',')

# Generate a query with all species
all_species = Species.objects.all()
# Generate a list with the separately filtered species
filtered_species = [all_species.filter(tags__description=c) for c in tag_list]
# Join the filtered species together using the same method :)
species = reduce(and_, filtered_species, all_species)
```

Comment: Aaah, thanks! But this will give me a list that is based on OR. Where as I want only ones that match all the items in the list

Comment: Oops... you're right, in that case it's not as easy as I'd hoped :) I'll update the answer.

Comment: Great, this works. how would it compare to :  species = Species.objects.filter(tags__description__in=tag_list).annotate(num_tags=Count('tags__description')).filter(num_tags=len(tag_list))

Comment: It would depend on the database how it's actually being executed. The query I posted makes a separate join for every tag (which means 2 joins per tag extra due to the ManyToMany relation). Your version just selects anything with only a single matching tag and does a filter after already getting all of the rows. Basically it's a bit of a trade-off between query planning time and result filtering time. Depending on the amount of results one or the other could provide better results.

Answer (score 1):

I think another way of doing this would be:

```
tag_list = request.GET.get('q').split(',')
species = Species.objects.all().distinct()
for tag in tag_list:
    species = species.filter(tags__description=tag)
else:
    species = Species.objects.none()
```