# Django Many-To-One relationship filter set

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a couple models setup like so:

```
Group(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=255)

Thing(models.Model):
    location = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

That's just an example to illustrate the relationship, so forgive any syntax errors.

My question is, how can find a group which has a particular set of locations? I should be able to access the Things associated with a Group by using:

```
Group.thing_set
```

Right? So is there any way I can filter based on what items are within the thing_set? I'm thinking something along the lines of this.

```
Group.objects.filter(thing_set.location in ["Location A", "Location B"]).all()
```

Hopefully this would return to me every group which contains things from both Location A and Location B. Any suggestions or a push in the right direction would be very helpful!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) you have to use the name of the model as your query operator:

> To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model.

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models


class Group(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField(max_length=255)


class Thing(models.Model):
    location = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView


class ReverseFK(ListView):
    model = Group

    def get_queryset(self):
        g = Group.objects.create(name="example")
        g.save()
        Thing.objects.create(location="here", group=g)
        return Group.objects.filter(thing__location__in=["here","there"])
```

[Working code example on github](https://github.com/arpheno/ReverseForeignKeyFilterExample)

Comment: This is really really close to what I want. Your example is super helpful! The one problem is that it seems to return groups which have things in "here" OR in "there". I would like the group to be returned only if it has both of them in it's set.

Comment: You got me enough in the right direction to figure it out. Here's where I found the final solution to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list