# Django filter where ManyToMany field contains ALL of list

Tags: python, django

I have a `CartItem` model with a ManyToMany field to a `AttributeChoice` model. So for example a `CartItem` can have `AttributeChoice` "Small" and "Red".

I want to then find my `CartItem` that both have attributes "Small" and "Red". If I do the following:

```
CartItem.objects.get(cart=cart, product=product, attribute__in=attribute_list)
```

Where `attribute_list` is a list of `AttributeChoice` objects for "Small" and "Red". Then I will also get objects that only have "Small" or "Red", but not both.

So this query would both match:

- CartItem A, Small, Red
- CartItem B, Small
- CartItem C, Red

While what I want is a query that would only match CartItem A.

Now... I could create a lot of AND-statements, but I need a solution that is flexible and can contain 1 or 100 of attributes to filter for. So to pass it a list of objects would be great.

Ideas?

Comment: please show your model classes

Comment: mfcovington was correct. There was a duplicate question formed in a different manner with a correct answer. I'll post the answer below here as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution to this problem was posted in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8637972/2335675).

This is how I wrote my query:

```
CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, product=product, attribute__in=attribute_list).annotate(num_attr=Count('attribute')).filter(num_attr=len(attribute_list))
```