# Check the existence of instance with Django ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, manytomanyfield

**Hello Awesome People!**

How to check whether a similar record is already in database with `ManyToManyField()`:

```
class Room():
     created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
     allowed_users = models.ManyToMany(User,related_name='rooms_as_guest')
     is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

In my view before creating a new room, I want to **make sure there wasn't an active room with exactly the same participants.**

*The following example won't work, it's just to show you what I expect*

```
 allowed_users = User.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.get("ids",[]))
 if allowed_users:
     Room.objects.get_or_create(
         created_by = request.user,
         allowed_users = allowed_users, # won't work
         is_active = True,
     )
```

**How could I proceed to do what I want?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `allowed_users` is a `ManyToMany` Field and so, Room needs to created before adding Users to it.

See official documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships

Now the other problem is we need to get an existing room with the same set of users, which is already answered in a similar question here:

[Django filter where ManyToMany field contains ALL of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963210/django-filter-where-manytomany-field-contains-all-of-list)

Try below:

```
from django.db.models import Count

allowed_users = User.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.get("ids",[]))
if allowed_users:
    room = Room.objects.filter(allowed_users__in=allowed_users).annotate(num_users=Count('allowed_users')).filter(num_users=len(allowed_users)).first()
    if not room:
        room = Room.objects.create(created_by=request.user, is_active=True)
        room.allowed_users.add(*allowed_users)
```

Comment: I want to check whether there wasn't an active room with exactly the same participants, if yes, get the room instead of creating a new one

Comment: @EuChi got it, modifying it.

Comment: This seems perfect, can you explain the part where you have `annotate` and `Count` ..... `.annotate(num_users=Count('allowed_users')).filter(num_users=len(allowed_users))`

Comment: `annotate` is used for `group_by` operation and then, getting only the annotated values like `num_users`. 
`Count` is used to get count of each `group` from `group_by` operation.
and then`.filter(num_users=len(allowed_users)` will add a `having` clause to the query.

Comment: You can get the exact SQL query by appending `.query` on the query-set

Let `allowed_users` = [1,2,3,4,5]
then `len(allowed_users)` will be 5

Query would look like:
SELECT "rooms"."id", COUNT("room_users"."user_id") AS "num_users"
FROM "rooms"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "room_users" ON ("room"."id" = "room_users"."room_id")
WHERE ("room_users"."user_id" IN (1,2,3,4,5))
GROUP BY "room"."id"
HAVING COUNT("room_users"."user_id") = 5

Comment: awesome, I improved it a little bit. Which one is faster then, yours or the one of @Bott0610 ? I prefer  yours because it is totally Django ORM, but in case the other is faster, I would go with

Comment: @EuChi It's always better to filter data at Database level using filter and aggregation as it handles filtering in a much more efficient manner than at App level.
So you can definitely go on with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an object like that with a ManyToMany field because the object must exist before you can create an intermediary object that represents your m2m relationship. You would have to do something like:

```
allowed_users = User.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.get("ids", [])).order_by('id')

room = None
for r in up.rooms.filter(is_active=True):
    if list(allowed_users) == list(r.allowed_users.all().order_by('id')):
        room = r # get the existing room
        break

if not room:
    room = Room.objects.create(
        created_by = request.user,
        is_active = True
    )
    room.allowed_users.add(*allowed_users)
```

You'd have to ensure allowed_users are in the same order as room.allowed_users however.

[Check the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for more info

Comment: if get_or_create is done, chances are that allowed_users will be added to an existing room.
Instead a new room should be created, if no room with the allowed_users exist.

Comment: I want to check whether there wasn't an active room with exactly the same participants, if yes, get the room instead of creating a new one

Comment: `allowed_users` is a queryset, not a list... the comparison won't work. but I got your point

Comment: @EuChi Right, fixed with ordering as well.

Comment: I think this will work, but there's no better way instead of for loop??

Comment: @EuChi I've mentioned another way below, of handling this in DB query itself, which would be more efficient.