# Django_filter incorrectly filters array in object

Tags: django, api, filter

I have ManyToMany field in my model "Product" which is called combinations and it includes some objects, that have slug and name field. I tried to filter by slug field, but if the product contains 2 slugs (for example red_wine and white_wine), django returns this product twice, but i need it to return only once.

Models.py:

```
class Combination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=120)
class Product(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey('Collection', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    combination = models.ManyToManyField('Combination', blank=True)
```

Views.py:

```
class CharInFilter(django_filters.BaseInFilter, django_filters.CharFilter):
    pass

class CollectionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    collection = CharInFilter(field_name='collection__slug', lookup_expr='in')
    combination = CharInFilter(field_name='combination__slug', lookup_expr='in')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['collection', 'combination']

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = CollectionFilter
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change `queryset = Product.objects.all()` to `queryset = Product.objects.distinct()`.

This will change your SQL query to `SELECT DISTINT ...`

For more info, you can check the docs [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

Edit:

I seem to have misunderstood the question. To answer you question:

Given that you pass the correct parameters in your url, filtering on a relationship like this (`combination__slug`), will return all Products for which *at least* one of their related combinations' slugs is in the list `['white_wine', 'red_wine']`.

To achieve what you want, you should check out [this question and it's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963210/django-filter-where-manytomany-field-contains-all-of-list)

Comment: Yeah, it works fine, but it works differently. For exapmple the 1st object contains "red_wine" and "white_wine" and 2nd object conatins "white_wine". When i set ?combination=?white_wine it should show me two objects, but when i set combination=?white_wine,red_whine, it should return only 1st object. Not this code returns the 1st and the 2nd objects with combination=?white_wine,red_whine. It is a little bit wrong. Have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the right arguments? `?combination=?white_wine,red_whine` is not a correct way to add query_paramaters. `?combination=white_wine,red_wine` is.

Comment: I was mistaken when I wrote. I pass arguments as you wrote, but still does not work correctly

Comment: You could probably look into MethodFilter, which allows you to define more complex filters, but I'm not exactly sure how you would implement it with a list of values.