# How to annotate Count with a condition in a Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Using Django ORM, can one do something like `queryset.objects.annotate(Count('queryset_objects', gte=VALUE))`. Catch my drift?

---

Here's a quick example to use for illustrating a possible answer:

In a Django website, content creators submit articles, and regular users view (i.e. read) the said articles. Articles can either be published (i.e. available for all to read), or in draft mode. The models depicting these requirements are:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Readership(models.Model):
    reader = models.ForeignKey(User)
    which_article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    what_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**My question is:** How can I get all published articles, sorted by unique readership from the last 30 mins? I.e. I want to count how many distinct (unique) views each published article got in the last half an hour, and then produce a list of articles sorted by these distinct views.

---

I tried:

```
date = datetime.now()-timedelta(minutes=30)
articles = Article.objects.filter(published=True).extra(select = {
  "views" : """
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM myapp_readership
    JOIN myapp_article on myapp_readership.which_article_id = myapp_article.id
  WHERE myapp_readership.reader_id = myapp_user.id
  AND myapp_readership.what_time > %s """ % date,
}).order_by("-views")
```

This sprang the error: **syntax error at or near "01"** (where "01" was the datetime object inside extra). It's not much to go on.

Comment: with `unique view` do you mean multiple views by the same reader count as one?

Comment: Yes exactly, multiple views, but by the same person, count as one. I think distinct() will need to be used here.

Comment: see if this gives you the number of unique views per article, then you'll filter/sort/limit them `Article.objects.values('readership__reader').annotate(numviews=Count('readership'))`

Comment: Yea well I got till this point too, but everything kind of goes out the window when I try to make "within last 30 mins" work.

Comment: try with `Article.objects.values('readership__reader').annotate(numviews=Count('readership‌​')).filter(readership__what_time__lt=threshold)`, where `threshold = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=30)`

Comment: okay, intriguing. Quick clarificational question while I try this: doesn't filter limit the set to only objects less than the threshold? I wanted **all** published objects, sorted by how much unique readership they received in the last 30 mins. So for instance, ones that got 0 would appear at the end of the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95426/discussion-between-pynchia-and-hassan-baig).

Answer (score 160, accepted):

#### For django >= 1.8

Use [Conditional Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, IntegerField
Article.objects.annotate(
    numviews=Count(Case(
        When(readership__what_time__lt=treshold, then=1),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
)
```

**Explanation:**
normal query through your articles will be annotated with `numviews` field. That field will be constructed as a CASE/WHEN expression, wrapped by Count, that will return 1 for readership matching criteria and `NULL` for readership not matching criteria. Count will ignore nulls and count only values.

You will get zeros on articles that haven't been viewed recently and you can use that `numviews` field for sorting and filtering.

Query behind this for PostgreSQL will be:

```
SELECT
    "app_article"."id",
    "app_article"."author",
    "app_article"."published",
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN "app_readership"."what_time" < 2015-11-18 11:04:00.000000+01:00 THEN 1
        ELSE NULL END
    ) as "numviews"
FROM "app_article" LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_readership"
    ON ("app_article"."id" = "app_readership"."which_article_id")
GROUP BY "app_article"."id", "app_article"."author", "app_article"."published"
```

If we want to track only unique queries, we can add distinction into `Count`, and make our `When` clause to return value, we want to distinct on.

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, CharField, F
Article.objects.annotate(
    numviews=Count(Case(
        When(readership__what_time__lt=treshold, then=F('readership__reader')), # it can be also `readership__reader_id`, it doesn't matter
        output_field=CharField(),
    ), distinct=True)
)
```

That will produce:

```
SELECT
    "app_article"."id",
    "app_article"."author",
    "app_article"."published",
    COUNT(
        DISTINCT CASE WHEN "app_readership"."what_time" < 2015-11-18 11:04:00.000000+01:00 THEN "app_readership"."reader_id"
        ELSE NULL END
    ) as "numviews"
FROM "app_article" LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_readership"
    ON ("app_article"."id" = "app_readership"."which_article_id")
GROUP BY "app_article"."id", "app_article"."author", "app_article"."published"
```

#### For django < 1.8 and PostgreSQL

You can just use `raw` for executing SQL statement created by newer versions of django. Apparently there is no simple and optimized method for querying that data without using `raw` (even with `extra` there are some problems with injecting required `JOIN` clause).

```
Articles.objects.raw('SELECT'
    '    "app_article"."id",'
    '    "app_article"."author",'
    '    "app_article"."published",'
    '    COUNT('
    '        DISTINCT CASE WHEN "app_readership"."what_time" < 2015-11-18 11:04:00.000000+01:00 THEN "app_readership"."reader_id"'
    '        ELSE NULL END'
    '    ) as "numviews"'
    'FROM "app_article" LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_readership"'
    '    ON ("app_article"."id" = "app_readership"."which_article_id")'
    'GROUP BY "app_article"."id", "app_article"."author", "app_article"."published"')
```

Comment: excellent solution, upvoted. Still, does it count unique views?

Comment: @Hassan Baig unfortunately, for older django versions you can only do it by `extra` or raw query.

Comment: Yea that's what I thought. For instance, here's an extra query I tried (gave me a syntax error): `articles = Article.objects.filter(published=True).extra(select={'views':'SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT reader_id) FROM myapp_readership AS readership WHERE (readership.what_time > %s AND readership.which_article_id=readership.which_article_id)'},select_params=(‌​threshold,),).order_by('-views')` *threshold* being the time delta of 30 mins.

Comment: @Pynchia of course. We can add `distinct=True` into `Count` and return value that we want to distinct on, instead of 1.

Comment: @HassanBaig putting sub-query will be really slow in this case, but you can use SQL code from queries created by django >= 1.8 in you `extra`, there is just need to trick django, so it will create joins and group by for us. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hmm so trying it with extra() gives me an error: 
**aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY**. If I put a datetime object in select_params, the error changes to **invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "date"** (here `date` was set to `datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=30)`)

Comment: edited the question with another "extra" approach I tried.

Comment: Answer was edited, so it now contains use of `raw` for django < 1.8, and fixed code for django >= 1.8.

Comment: Thanks' Man. Two clock search in internet, before looked this page

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer and explanation, but what is `output_field=1` means? I saw your another example using `CharField` rather than `1`

Comment: There should be `CharField` instead of `1`, but I think in this example it won't matter, `Count` will ignore it.

Comment: The additional part about distinct saved me :) Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 81):

For django >= 2.0 you can use [Conditional aggregation with a `filter` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation) in the aggregate functions:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Count, Q # need import

Article.objects.annotate(
    numviews=Count(
        'readership__reader__id', 
        filter=Q(readership__what_time__gt=timezone.now() - timedelta(minutes=30)), 
        distinct=True
    )
)
```

Comment: This should definitely be the answer in preference to the answer below!