# How to sort a Django queryset by a conditional aggregation of related items?

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-queryset, django-orm

How can I use the Django ORM to sort all objects in a queryset by a *conditional* aggregation of related items? Django 1.8 and higher explicitly have [conditional aggregation support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation), I need an answer for **Django < 1.8**. This will obviously involve 3 or 4 queries. Here are example models an answerer can use to illustrate her answer:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class GroupTraffic(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    which_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    time_of_visit = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Users own chat groups, and other users can visit the said chat groups. The question to answer is: How can one produce a sorted list of *all* groups, such that it's sorted by the *unique* traffic each group has seen in the *last 60 mins*? Groups that have seen a lot of unique visitors in the last 60 mins get sorted to the top, groups with almost zero (or zero) such traffic appear at the bottom of the list.

This is a conditional aggregation question because, essentially, we need to annotate to each group object, a Count of all related, unique grouptraffic objects that were logged in the past 60 mins.

Can someone show me how to use the Django ORM to solve this for < 1.8? I already know how to do it for >= 1.8 via conditional aggregation (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33777815/4936905)), and I don't want to do it via SQL queries in raw or extra.

Comment: By unique traffic, I mean not double counting if it's the visitor with the same ID. I.e. using `distinct` in the Django ORM.

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?

Comment: Huge list man, hold on, I'll put some of the closest ones here.

Comment: Query 1: This ones doesn't take the last 60 mins' traffic into account: `groups = Group.objects.annotate(views=Count('grouptraffic__visitor', distinct=True))`.

Comment: Query 2: These don't take *all groups* into account: date = `datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=1)`
`new_traff = GroupTraffic.objects.filter(time__gte=date, which_group__private='0').distinct('visitor').values_list('id',flat=True)`
`trendingGrp_ids = GroupTraffic.objects.filter(id__in=new_traff).values('which_group').annotate(total=Count('which_group')).order_by('-total')`
`trendingGrps = [Group.objects.filter(id=grp['which_group']).extra(select={"views":grp['total']})[0] for grp in trendingGrp_ids]`
`return trendingGrps`

Comment: Query 3: These didn't work, I'm not sure why: `date = datetime.now()-timedelta(minutes=30)`
`articles = Group.objects.filter(published=True).extra(select = {
  "views" : """
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM myapp_grouptraffic
    JOIN myapp_group on myapp_grouptraffic.which_group_id = myapp_group.id
  WHERE myapp_grouptraffic.visitor_id = user.id
  AND myapp_grouptraffic.time_of_visit > %s """ % date,
}).order_by("-views")`

Comment: That's it for the ones that came the closest. I was way off in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter on the `time_of_visit` and it should work fine:

```
one_hour_ago = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=1)
recent_groups = Group.objects.filter(grouptraffic__time_of_visit>=one_hour_ago)
visitors = recent_groups.annotate(views=Count('grouptraffic__visitor', distinct=True))
```

Then get all of the older groups, with an `extra` field for the empty views:

```
older_groups = Group.objects.filter(grouptraffic__time_of_visit < one_hour_ago).extra(select={'visits':0})
```

Then concatenate them together with a pipe:

```
all_groups = visitors | older_groups
```

Comment: Won't this *not include* groups that didn't log a visit in the past one hour? I want to include all groups, just that those without a visit in the past hour ought to be sorted last.

Comment: Okay and one more requirement is sorting the list by *hottest* group first. I should straight up run an "order_by('-views')" on "all_groups" at the end?.

Comment: That should work. If not, you could sort each query independently and then merge.

Comment: Okay either way. I'm taking this for a spin, logically this works. I'll report back in a bit.

Comment: Btw, that would be `all_groups = visitors | older_groups`, no?