# How filter annotated data in django-queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to calculate count of approved comments?

```
news_list = News.objects.all()\
    .annotate(
        comments_count=Count(
            'comments__id', 
            comments__status=COMMENT_STATUS_APPROVED
        )
    )
```

But the second condition of Count-function is not working. How to filter annotate-function

Comment: Filtering on annotations is not possible in Django. You will have to use custom SQL. This blog entry may be useful: https://timmyomahony.com/blog/filtering-annotations-django/

Comment: @Leistungsabfall Thanks for this link! I was changed the my queryset to use extra-select.

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question on [how to annotate a count with a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33777815/2167797) with a detailed answer and explanation of the SQL.

You **can** do [conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation), using the [conditional expression Case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case). The example in the docs is shows operation on a single model, but you can use the normal methods for inter-model relationships. The following QuerySet should be what you're looking for-

```
class NewsQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def with_comment_counts(self):
        query = self
        query = query.annotate(
            comment_count=Sum(
                Case(When(comment__status=COMMENT_STATUS_APPROVED, then=1
                          default=0,
                          output_field=IntegerField())
            ),
        return query
```