# Django aggregation multiple filters

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project that allows users to create their own Projects and add multiple Skills to each Project.
I am trying to write a view that will allow me to display the name of each Skill as well as the Count of that Skill for all of that particular user Profile's Projects that are published.

For example, if a user has three projects where they've added the Skill "HTML" I'd like to show HTML (3) on their Profile, and so on.

Below is my current code which mostly works however it displays the count for that Skill from ALL user projects and not the specific user whose profile is being viewed.

**Models:**

```
#accounts/models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    #...
    skills          = models.ManyToManyField('skills.skill')

#projects/models.py
class Project(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #...
    published       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    skills          = models.ManyToManyField('skills.skill')
    #...

#skills/models.py
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Views:**

```
#accounts/views.py
def profile(request, username):
    user            = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    skill_counts    = Skill.objects.annotate(num_projects=Count('project')).filter(project__user_id=user.id).order_by('-num_projects')[:10]


    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {
        'user': user, 
        'skill_counts': skill_counts,
        })
```

**Template:**

```
#accounts/templates/accounts/profile.html
{% for skill in skill_counts %}
    <div class="skill-container">
        <div class="label-skill">{{ skill.name }}</div> <div class="label-skill-count">
        {{skill.project_set.count}}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to annotate Count with a condition in a Django queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775011/how-to-annotate-count-with-a-condition-in-a-django-queryset)

Comment: Did the answer reply to your question? If so, consider accepting it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note that I'm voting to close this as this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33777815/1622937).*

---

Basically you need to use django's conditional expressions [`Case` and `When`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case).

Here is a quick example of how this could look:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When
# ...
Skill.objects.annotate(
    num_porjects=Count(Case(
        When(project__user_id=user.id, then=1),
        output_field=CharField(),
    ))
)
```