# Conditional Expression in Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I have 3 models: `Product, Brand, Shop`. I want to count `Products` which are available for `Brands` in the given `Shop`.
For example:
`Adidas   50`
`Puma     25`
 Now I have:

```
queryset = Brand.objects
            .filter(brand_id__in=id_list)
            .order_by('brand_name')

queryset =  queryset.annotate(amount_of_products=Count('products'))
```

But this gives me an amount of products from *all* shops.

I have tried like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775011/how-to-annotate-count-with-a-condition-in-a-django-queryset):

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
            amount_of_products=Count(
                Case(When(shops__shop_name__in=[shop], then=1))
            ))
```

But I get an `amount_of_products = 1` for every `Brand` in the list.
**Is there a way to do this conditional expression in Django 1.11?**

Answer (score 0):

Actually managed to fix that :)

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
            amount_of_products=Count(
                Case(When(products__shop__shop_name__in=[shop], then=1))
            ))
```

That was just improper `ForeignKey` use.