# Django count related objects with condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to filter the results before counting. In below code, I am counting the total number of workers for each Ticket Counter.

```
class TicketCounterList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = TicketCounter.objects.filter(ticket_counter_is_deleted=False)
            .annotate(num_workers=Count('workers'))
    serializer_class = TicketCounterSerializer
```

`workers` in the above code is the `related_name` from another model ( `WorkerToTicketCounter` model). What I want to do is, I want to be able to filter workers with a condition `is_deleted= True` rather than counting all workers. Is it possible? I am using Django 1.11.13

Is there anything like below

```
queryset = TicketCounter.objects.filter(ticket_counter_is_deleted=False)
            .annotate(num_workers=Count('workers',filter="xxxx"))
```

get it? I want to filter the `workers`.

EDIT: 
My Models:

```
class TicketCounter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ticket_counter_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    ticket_counter_description = models.CharField(max_length=1500, default="")
    ticket_counter_address = models.CharField(max_length=1500, default="")


class WorkerToTicketCounter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ticket_counter = models.ForeignKey(TicketCounter,related_name="workers")
    worker = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='worker_for_ticket_counter')
```

My Serializer:

```
class TicketCounterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    num_workers = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = TicketCounter
        fields = (
            'ticket_counter_name',
            'ticket_counter_description',
            'ticket_counter_address',
            'num_workers',
        )
```

Comment: Kindly add your models to be more clear.

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775011/how-to-annotate-count-with-a-condition-in-a-django-queryset and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752268/how-to-filter-objects-for-count-annotation-in-django

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter objects for count annotation in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752268/how-to-filter-objects-for-count-annotation-in-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), you can do filtering in the `Count`, but this will not help us here.

What we however *can* do is *sum* up the `workers__is_deleted`, or its negation. For example if we want to return the number of workers that are *not* deleted:

```
from django.db.models import F, IntegerField, Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class TicketCounterList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = TicketCounter.objects.filter(
        ticket_counter_is_deleted=False
    ).annotate(
        num_workers=Cast(
            Coalesce(Sum(Value(1) - F('workers__is_deleted')), Value(0)),
            IntegerField()
        )
    )
    serializer_class = TicketCounterSerializer
```

Or if you want to count the deleted workers:

```
from django.db.models import F, IntegerField, Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class TicketCounterList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = TicketCounter.objects.filter(
        ticket_counter_is_deleted=False
    ).annotate(
        num_workers=Cast(
            Coalesce(Sum(F('workers__is_deleted')), Value(0)),
            IntegerField()
        )
    )
    serializer_class = TicketCounterSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks for answering again. I am getting import errors for `Coalesce` and `V`.

Comment: @Naroju: yes, I think there have been some renamings and movements in the Django library. It is probably now fixed.

Comment: Small doubt. Can I annotate another `related_name` of another model for counting. Like chaining.. ?

Comment: Counting different related objects concurrently typically is inefficient, as wel as dangerous since the different joins can act as a *multiplier*.

Comment: Yeah. Then how to do it?

Comment: @Naroju: you could technically speaking do this with subqueries. But I think by upgrading to Django-2.0, you save yourself a lot of trouble, since it has a filter, and then this "hacky" solution is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks again for answering second time :)