# Django Querysets - Relations match all subqueries OR refer to joined table's field in a second filter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm trying to construct a Django queryset for a model where all of that model's relations are represented by some subquery or subqueries.
For example, Bands have Musicians and Instruments through Memberships. I want to find all bands where two members play the guitar, or where one member plays guitar and another plays drums.

The closest I've come is with one of the suggestions from this similar but not-quite-right question: [Django filter queryset __in for *every* item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list)

It will probably be easier to explain what I'm trying to do and why the above solutions didn't work with an example.

**Models:**

```
class Instrument(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Musician(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Band(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    musicians = models.ManyToManyField(Musician, through='Membership')
    instruments = models.ManyToManyField(Instrument, through='Membership')


class Membership(models.Model):
    band = models.ForeignKey(Band, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='memberships')
    musician = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='memberships')
    instrument = models.ForeignKey(Instrument, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='memberships')
```

**Data:**

```
Instruments
id | name
 1 | Guitar
 2 | Drums
 3 | Keyboard
 4 | Vocals

Musicians
id | name
 1 | John
 2 | Paul
 3 | George
 4 | Ringo

Bands
id | name
 1 | The Beatles
 2 | The Beadles
 3 | The Beagles

Memberships
id | band_id | musician_id | instrument_id
 1 |       1 |           1 |             1
 2 |       1 |           2 |             1
 3 |       2 |           1 |             1
 4 |       2 |           2 |             1
 5 |       3 |           1 |             1
 6 |       3 |           2 |             2
```

In a slightly more digestible form, there are three bands with two members/instruments each. They are:

```
The Beatles: John/Guitar, Paul/Guitar
The Beadles: John/Guitar, Paul/Guitar
The Beagles: John/Guitar, Paul/Drums
```

**Problem:**

**Part 1 - working example**
I want to find all the bands where two members play guitar.

```
guitar = Instrument.objects.get(name='Guitar')

guitar_memberships_1 = Membership.objects.filter(instrument=guitar)
guitar_memberships_2 = Membership.objects.filter(instrument=guitar)
guitar_memberships = guitar_memberships_1 | guitar_memberships_2
# Yes, all three of these querysets are equal. I'm writing my code 
# this way because I don't always know that they will be equal,
# and because I specifically want bands where TWO members play guitar.
# Hopefully this will be more clear in the part 3 of my example.

Band.objects.filter(memberships__in=guitar_memberships).annotate(num_mems=Count('memberships')).filter(num_mems=2).count()
# num_mems=2 - in reality, 2 might be replaced with something like len(memberships), 
# where memberships is a list of querysets
```

This works, or at least seems to. It returns 2, since there are two bands where two members play guitar.

**Part 2 - this doesn't work** 
I want to find all bands where at least one member plays the guitar.

```
guitar = Instrument.objects.get(name='Guitar')

guitar_memberships = Membership.objects.filter(instrument=guitar)
Band.objects.filter(memberships__in=guitar_memberships).annotate(num_mems=Count('memberships')).filter(num_mems=1).count()
```

This returns 1 - The Beagles, where exactly one member plays guitar

I want it to return 3, since there are three bands where at least one member plays guitar.

**Part 3 - this also doesn't work**
I want to find all bands where one member plays guitar and one member plays drums

```
guitar = Instrument.objects.get(name='Guitar')
drums = Instrument.objects.get(name='Drums')

# This ultimately uses the same process as the example in part 1, but is closer to my actual code
memberships = []
memberships.append(Membership.objects.filter(instrument=guitar))
memberships.append(Membership.objects.filter(instrument=drums))
mem_queryset = Instrument.objects.none()
for mem in memberships:
    mem_queryset = mem_queryset | mem

Band.objects.filter(memberships__in=mem_queryset).annotate(num_mems=Count('memberships')).filter(num_mems=len(memberships)).count()
```

Unlike example 1, this doesn't work. It returns 3.

len(memberships) resolves to 2 in this case. So it includes The Beagles because there are two members whose memberships are in the combined queryset, but the same is true of the bands with two guitarists.

In case it helps, here is some raw SQL that accomplishes what I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*
FROM bands_band b
INNER JOIN bands_membership m1 ON m1.band_id = b.id AND m1.instrument_id = 1
INNER JOIN bands_membership m2 ON m2.band_id = b.id AND m2.id != m1.id AND m2.instrument_id = 2;
```

For what it's worth, I also had a query that used subselects working, but I can't remember how I did and haven't been able to recreate it. It similarly hinged on comparing the id of the second membership to the id of the first membership to avoid bands where the same membership was joined twice. I've been unable to recreate this approach using Django querysets, i.e., I've been unsuccessful in finding a way to refer to a field from one joined table in the filter for a second joined table, so I can't do `m2.id != m1_id`

I'd prefer to avoid using raw SQL for this, obviously, and if possible, I'd also like to avoid using extra(), since it seems Django plans to deprecate it at some point

@karthikr:
Here are some attempts I made using the approach suggested in your edit.

```
guitar = Instrument.objects.get(name='Guitar')
drums = Instrument.objects.get(name='Drums')

memberships = []
memberships.append(Membership.objects.filter(instrument=guitar))
memberships.append(Membership.objects.filter(instrument=drums))

bands = Band.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(memberships__in=x) for x in memberships)))
bands = bands.annotate(num_mems=Count('memberships')).filter(num_mems__gte=len(memberships))
```

`bands.count()` returns 0, and printing `bands.query` returns this:

```
SELECT 
    `bands_band`.`id`, 
    `bands_band`.`name`, 
    COUNT(`bands_membership`.`id`) AS `num_mems` 
FROM `bands_band` INNER JOIN `bands_membership` ON ( `bands_band`.`id` = `bands_membership`.`band_id` ) 
WHERE (
    (`bands_membership`.`id`) IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `bands_membership` U0 WHERE U0.`instrument_id` = 1) 
AND (`bands_membership`.`id`) IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `bands_membership` U0 WHERE U0.`instrument_id` = 2)
)
GROUP BY `bands_band`.`id` HAVING COUNT(`bands_membership`.`id`) >= 2 ORDER BY NULL
```

From the query it's more clear that it's returning 0 here because no bands_membership.id will be in both of those sub-selects at the same time. I can't use OR instead of AND, because that will get me all three bands instead of just the one with one drummer and one guitarist (all guitarists will meet the condition of being in the first subselect).

I'm not sure I understand what your getting at, but I also tried an approach using unions and values_list():

```
memberships1 = Membership.objects.filter(instrument=guitar)
memberships2 = Membership.objects.filter(instrument=drums)
memberships = memberships1 | memberships2
memberships = memberships.values_list('id')

bands = Band.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(memberships__in=x) for x in memberships)))
bands = bands.annotate(num_mems=Count('memberships')).filter(num_mems__gte=len(memberships))
```

`bands.count()` returns 0 again, and this is the query:

```
SELECT 
    `bands_band`.`id`, 
    `bands_band`.`name`, 
    COUNT(`bands_membership`.`id`) AS `num_mems` 
FROM `bands_band` 
INNER JOIN `bands_membership` ON ( `bands_band`.`id` = `bands_membership`.`band_id` ) 
WHERE (
    `bands_membership`.`id` IN (1) AND `bands_membership`.`id` IN (2) AND `bands_membership`.`id` IN (3) 
AND `bands_membership`.`id` IN (4) AND `bands_membership`.`id` IN (5) AND `bands_membership`.`id` IN (6)
)
GROUP BY `bands_band`.`id` HAVING COUNT(`bands_membership`.`id`) >= 6 ORDER BY NULL
```

I think this one is essentially the same as the above.

Since I'm not sure I'm reading you correctly, I also tried

```
bands = Band.objects.filter(memberships__in=memberships).annotate(num_mems=Count('memberships')).filter(num_mems__gte=2)
```

using the values_list approach. This gets all three bands, which I think is expected, but not the result I'm aiming for.