# Django Q filter returning no results on many to many field

Tags: django, filter

It is my understanding (from what I observed in my code) that if I do something like:

```
Distinct_Alert.objects.filter(somefield=somevalue)
```

I should get rows that exactly match that query, versus say

```
Distinct_Alert.objects.filter(somefield=somevalue, entities__in=somelist)
```

say that my list comprises of 3 elements, and I have rows that may match one of the elements, then it will return that row. What I'm trying to do is to fetch the row ONLY if it matches all of the elements in the list, is that possible?

I've tried doing the following:

```
Distinct_Alert.objects.filter(Q(alert_type=alert_type) & reduce(operator.and_, [Q(entities=c) for c in entities]))
```

entities is a many to many field, and for some reasons, this is always returning no matches, even though I can see rows that match this exact criteria. Does Q not work with many to many fields?

As per suggestions I've tried chaining and it works, however this approach feels wrong and wonky

```
chained_query = Distinct_Alert.objects.filter(alert_type=alert_type)
for entity in entities:
    chained_query = chained_query.filter(entities=entity[0])
```

This returns the proper result, but this doesn't:

```
Distinct_Alert.objects.filter(Q(alert_type=alert_type) & reduce(operator.and_, [Q(entities=c[0]) for c in entities]))
```

Also, wouldn't the chained filters run into potential issues where the searched subset is smaller than the row contained set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django filter queryset \_\_in for \*every\* item in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list)

Comment: Hey @ShangWang I've edited the question to more accurately describe my situation and I do not believe it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Q:

```
from django.contrib.db.models import Q
```

and then

```
 Distinct_Alert.objects.filter(somefield=somevalue).exclude(~Q(number__in=somelist))
```

Comment: I've updated my question with Q but still running into issues :(

Comment: When you know entities are m2m you get all of them as alert = Distinct_Alert.objects.get(id=alert_id) , and then entities = alert.entities.all() - this will return all entities, so you can exclude those in the list

Comment: I'm not trying to exclude them from the list, I'm trying to find the Distinct_Alert row that matches that, I need the alert type to match and the associated entities to match

Comment: If you know the list of entities you want to include you can just do Distingct_Alert.objects.filter(entities__in=entities_to_check_list).filter(somefield=somevalue)

Comment: entities__in is not an AND relationship, it will hit even if it matches only one element in the list

Comment: it is as its filter after filter - you narrow down the criteria

Comment: the double filter is not the concern, the concern is the entities__in==entities_to_check_list part, this will return a match regardless if it's an absolute match or partial match. Hence why I'm using Q now to make it an AND match. Unless I'm misunderstanding you'

Comment: is the entities__in=entities_to_check - single = , you are not comparing, it's done by django ORM for you

Comment: apologies, that was a typo, I meant entities__in=entities_to_check. The concern with using chained filters is that you will potentially run into subset matches, i.e. you matched on 3 searched criteria but there are actually 10 manytomany criteria matches.