# How can i make queryset in django for this scenario

Tags: django, python-2.7, filter, django-queryset

hi i have one dynamically generated list lets we assume

```
my_list = ['11','13','15']
```

my model.py is

```
class OptionProduct(models.Model):

    product_name = models.ForeignKey('products.Product', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Product'))
    option_name = models.ForeignKey(Options,null=True, blank=True)
    option_value = models.ForeignKey(OptionValue,null=True, blank=True)
```

my list is refer to option_value in OptionProduct table

now i want to get that product in which all option values are include

```
product_name |   option_value | option_name

1           |       11      |   1

1           |       13      |   1

2           |       11      |   1

2           |       13      |   1

3           |       11      |   1

3           |       13      |   1

2           |       15      |   2

1           |       15      |   2
```

so it want to get product_name 1 and 2 as a output because it have all three value of my_list in option_value
every time my_list is change so it work according to that

so how can i make query set in django

Comment: You should format your code first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django filter queryset \_\_in for \*every\* item in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this can be possible in two steps. try below query.

```
import collections
option_product_list = OptionProduct.objects.filter(option_value__id__in=my_list).values_list('product_name', flat=True)
output = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(list(option_product_list)).items() if count >= len(my_list)]
```