# Django: how to query all values in an array?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a checkbox with multiple values. For example, `hobbies`. When the user choose some `hobbies`, he wants to see the person who **has** all those hobbies.

I dont go into details for sake of clarity so here's how I read all the checked values and put them in my "big" query, which is, as you may guess: **`q`**:

```
hobbies2 = [int(l) for l in g.getlist('hobbies2')]
if len(hobbies2):
    q = q & Q(personne__hobbies2__in=hobbies2)
```

The problem is that it returns all persons who have a hobby in common (i.e. it's like "`or`", not "`and`").

How to get all those many to many values with a `and`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__in` operator is for filtering by a set. It is not meant for checking multiple values at once in a many-to-many relationship.

It literally translate to the following in SQL:

```
SELECT ... WHERE hobbies IN (1, 3, 4);
```

So you'd need to build your query using AND conditions. You can do this with consecutive filters:

```
queryset = Personne.objects.all()

# build up the queryset with multiple filters
for hobby in hobbies2:
    queryset = queryset.filter(hobbies2=hobby)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `personne__hobbies2=hobby` will *not* eliminate people when there's more than one hobby? For example: kayak = 1, ski = 2. This will filter first `personne__hobbies2=1` then after `personne__hobbies2=1`. Are you sure that it may work?

Comment: With consecutive Q objects doesnt work. I've tried the #1 solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list it doesnt work too.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've updated my answer to remove the Q queries. However, the consecutive filters should work since those are demonstrated in the link.