# Django REST Framework ManyToMany filter multiple values

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-rest-framework

I have two models, one defining users, the other defining labels on these users. I am using Django REST Framework to create an API. I would like to be able to query users containing at least the label ids 1 and 2.

For instance if the user's labels are:
`[(1,2), (1,2,3), (2,3), (1,3)]` I want the query to return
`[(1,2), (1,2,3)]`.

So far, I've managed to query users with a given label (let's say id=1) by doing: `/api/users/?labels=1`, but I am unable to query users with labels 1 and 2. I've tried `/api/users/?labels=1,2` or `/api/users/?labels=1&labels=2` but it returns some invalid users, i.e. users without labels 1 or 2...

**Github test repo:**

https://github.com/TheDimLebowski/drf-m2m-filter

**Code:**

### models.py

```
class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)

class User(models.Model):
    labels = models.ManyToManyField(Label)
```

### filters.py

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    labels = django_filters.filters.BaseInFilter(
        name='labels',
        lookup_type='in',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('labels',)
```

### serializers.py

```
class LabelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Label
        fields = ('id','name')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    labels = LabelSerializer(many = True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('labels',)
```

### views.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = UserFilter
    filter_fields = ('labels',)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can chain filters. For example, if you need all users which labels contain both `1` and `2` values, you can write a query like so:

```
User.objects.filter(labels=1).filter(labels=2)
```

`django-filters` does not support queries like this by default so you need a custom filter.

```
class M2MFilter(django_filters.Filter):

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if not value:
            return qs
    
        values = value.split(',')
        for v in values:
            qs = qs.filter(labels=v)
        return qs


class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    labels = M2MFilter(name='labels')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('labels',)
```

Now you can write labels id's comma-separated and get exactly what you need

```
/api/users/?labels=1,2
```

[Here is good answer about m2m queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm afraid it leads to the same problem... with all these notations:
`?labels=1&labels=2` `?labels=1,2` and `?labels=1&2`

Comment: @TheDimLebowski it will return users with labels `6`, `7` or `6 and 7`.

Comment: Can we restrict to labels `1 and 2` only?

Comment: @TheDimLebowski not `6 and 7` but `1 and 2` I wanted to say. You want to restrict base queryset? so you can do it in the field, just filter it by ids, `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Label.objects.filter(pk__in=[1,2]))` now it will filter by `1`,  `2`,   `1 and 2` only

Comment: Let me clarify. I want the base queryset to be all of the users. Now by querying `?labels=1&2` I want a list of users with labels `1 and 2`.

Comment: @TheDimLebowski yes I get it, maybe I'm just not full clearly explain it to you. One second, I'll update it in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122824/discussion-between-thedimlebowski-and-ivan-semochkin).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question and I found something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from rest_framework import viewsets

class YourViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # get lable infos here
        lables_info = self.request.query_params.get('lable')
        lables = lables_info.split(',')
        lable1, lable2 = lables[0], lables[1]

        return models.objects.fliter(
            Q(lable=lable1) | Q(lable=lable2)
        )
.......
```

Django==2.2.4

djangorestframework==3.10.2

django-filter==2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Using linked filters in `UserViewSet` as follows:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        labels = eval(self.request.query_params.get('labels', []))
        for label in labels:
            queryset = queryset.filter(labels__in=[label])
        return queryset
```

and querying like:

```
/api/users/?labels=[1,2]
```

seems to work!