# django rest-framework API returns empty due to end operation how to solve it

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am building an API using django rest-framwork.
this is my data,

```
[
    {
        "id": 24,
        "name": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 45,
        "name": "ADB"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Agriculture"
    },
    {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "Category external workforce, professional and business services"
    }]
```

it works fine if I provide a single item for the filter operation. like this.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/op-api/sec/?name=Agriculture
```

it returns me empty if I provide more then one item for the filtering purpose.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/op-api/sec/?name=Agriculture,ADB
```

but I want it should return data like this.

```
[
    {
        "id": 45,
        "name": "ADB"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Agriculture"
    }
]
```

here is my code for the API

```
class sec_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    serializer_class = sector_Serializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend , SearchFilter , OrderingFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['name',]
    search_fields = ['name',]

    def get_queryset(self) :
        all_sec = Sector.objects.all()
        return all_sec


class sector_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    class Meta :
        model = Sector
        fields = ['id' , 'name']
```

how can I update it so that it works fine.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39368843/13273054

Comment: @WaveShaper no it was not the answer but gave me the idea for the solution. thank you