# Django filter all that has certain names

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a problem very similar to 
[Django filter queryset __in for *every* item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list/8637972#8637972)

I need to select all `prospects` that have certain `certifications` as defined by

```
class Prospect(models.Model):
    certification = models.ManyToManyField(Certification, blank=True, related_name="certification_prospects")

class Certification(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

For example, if I have certifications ['CPA', 'PhD'] I want all prospects that have exactly CPA & PhD, if they have more or less than those two, I want to exclude them.

I'm using this solution, as give by the link earlier

```
def searchForProspectByCertifications(prospects, certifications):
    prospects = prospects.filter(certification__in=certifications).annotate(num_certifications=Count('certification')).filter(num_certifications=len(certifications))

    return prospects
```

But I'm receiving an error of `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'CPA'`

Comment: What content have given  prospects, certifications parameters in method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
prospects.filter(certification__name__in=certifications)
```