# Django Queryset filtering pk list over Manytomany

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset, django-1.9

I want to take a Queryset of Project.objects.all() and filter all Projects that contain a list of attributes chosen by the user.

**models.py**

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute)

## For the sake of this example, there are two Projects and two Attributes
## Project1 is associated to attr1 and attr2
## Project2 is associated to attr1
```

I found this: [Django Docs Complex Lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) and through other stackoverflow answers got to here:

**Non-working Code** (self.multiselect is a list of pks)

```
query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(attributes__pk=selection) for selection in self.multiselect))
return queryset.filter(query)
```

However this code provides an empty Queryset. I started doing some testing in the interactive shell to figure out what went wrong.

**Tests**

```
queryset = Project.objects.all()

########## & is not working
queryset.filter(Q(attributes__pk=1) & Q(attributes__pk=2))
# []

########## | has no issues
queryset.filter(Q(attributes__pk=1) | Q(attributes__pk=2))
# [<Project: Project1>, <Project: Project2>, <Project: Project1>]

########## & works on Project but not on Attribute
queryset.filter(Q(title__contains="Project") & Q(title__contains="1"))
# [<Project: Project1>]
```

It seems like & is not working on the ManytoMany relation between Project and Attribute. Is there a reason for this, is there a simple fix to the code that will make it work properly? Any help would be appreciated.

---

As a side note, the reduce function is returning exactly what it should

```
########## Reduce does not create an issue
Q(attributes__pk=1) & Q(attributes__pk=2)
# <Q: (AND: ('attributes__pk', 1), ('attributes__pk', 2))>
reduce(operator.and_, [Q(attributes__pk=selection) for selection in [1,2]])
# <Q: (AND: ('attributes__pk', 1), ('attributes__pk', 2))>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why `filter`, `Q` and `&` works. I thought about negating the negation, which led me to this solution.

```
Project.objects.exclude(~(Q(attributes__pk=1) & Q(attributes__pk=2)))
```

Using exclude and negating the original query filters with `Q` and `&` worked.

Comment: Yea. I am trying to figure out the math behind this, but it does seem to produce the desired output. Thank you <3 Edit: I guess there must be a bug with 'filter', 'Q' and '&' because the negation gives me everything but my desired output, so you would think that the non-negated form would give me my desired result. Nice catch ^^

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

As you say:

```
########## & is not working
queryset.filter(Q(attributes__pk=1) & Q(attributes__pk=2))
```

It should be:

```
attrs = Attribute.objects.filter(pk__in=self.multiselect)
Photo.objects.filter(attributes__in=attrs).annotate(num_attr=Count('attributes')).filter(num_attr=len(attrs))
```

see this: [Django filter queryset __in for *every* item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list)

Comment: Using attributes__in gives a list of all Projects with __any__ of the attributes selected, not Projects with __all__ of the attributes selected

Comment: @pieisawesome102 ```annotate(num_attr=Count('attributes')).filter(num_attr=len(attrs))``` This make sure all of the attributes selected.