# django filter list tag__in with "and" operator

Tags: python, django

I have a list for tags [11,12,13 14]

When I try to filter my items using tag

```
Model.objects.filter(title__contains=title,tag__in=[11,12],listType=listtype,status=1).all()
```

Its showing both item having tag 11 and 12. Than means, it was taking "OR" operation.

How can I get the Item list contain both tags 11 and 12. anyone please help

```
Model.objects.filter(tags=t1).filter(tags=t2).all()
```

This was the only thing working for me. how can I add multiple filter dynamically.

Comment: I think here is your answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list. Indeed could be a duplicate question

Comment: Indeed that is not the best solution I guess but should work Model.objects.filter(title__contains=title,tag__in=11,listType=listtype,status=1).filter(title__contains=title,tag__in=12,listType=listtype,status=1)all()

Comment: Model.objects.filter(tags=t1).filter(tags=t2). This was the only thing working for me. how can I add multiple filter dynamically.

Comment: Have a look at the last answer of that link

Comment: yeah, tried tags__contains but it was not working for me. may be because I'm using tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,null=True,blank=True)

Comment: @RoginThomas you can add `filter` calls in a loop: `qs = Models.objects...; for t in tags: qs = qs.filter(tags=t)`