# Django filter queryset __in exact matching

Tags: django, listview, filter, django-queryset, exact-match

I have models as below:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

class Permit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skill_course = models.ManyToManyField(
        Skill, related_name="+", blank=True,
    )

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(
        Skill, related_name="courses",blank=True,
    )
```

I want to filter Permit objects which have exact matching skills present in courses(skills are in courses), so I filtered list course and skills in view as below:

```
course = Course.objects.filter(students=self.request.user, date__lt=datetime.datetime.today())
skills = list(Skill.objects.filter(courses__in=course).distinct())
queryset = Permit.objects.filter(skill_course__in=skills)
```

But this is fuzzy matching, not exact matching. For example:

```
# only if list permit_a = user.skill_a, current user will get permit_a
permit_a = [A, B, C, D]
user.skill_a = [A, B, C, D]
```

but now `user.skill_a = [B, E, F]`, current user already got `permit_a`, I am trapped now, really appreciate for any advise, thanks so much in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/

Check out this SO question they propose an aggregation approach you can do something like 


`queryset = Permit.objects.filter(skill_course__in=skills).annotate(num_skills=Count('skills')).filter(num_skills=skills.count())`

Comment: Thanks Bhavani, I already read that post, I guess it's different? Cuz I always get wrong results, Do I need to define skill_course firstly? I changed my code into yours, nothing changed.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your models and views, you need to define skill_courses the permit needs, like this:

```
permit = get_object_or_404(Permit, pk=1)
skill_courses = permit.skill_course.all()
```

And then you need to change skills into 'exact matching' as below:

```
queryset = Permit.objects.filter(skill_course__in=[skill for skill in skill_courses if skill in skills])
```

Comment: Thanks so so so much, it works finally!!!!! Now I have a new problem, how to define skill_course the permit needs? Not to assign one with pk=1, but I have to define pk=pk, there are hundreds permits, some permit have one skill_course, and some permit have several skill_courses, I need to exact matching all, not just one permit as pk=1.........

Answer (score 0):

skills needs to be list of values not queryset objects. Use [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/) to fetch list of values from Skills object of your interest.

```
skills = Skill.objects.filter(courses__in=course).values_list('FIELD_OF_INTEREST', flat=True)
```

Comment: Hi Vinay, thanks for your answer, now I have a new problem, how to define skill_course the permit needs? Not to assign one item with 'pk=1', I have to define like pk=pk, Cuz there are hundreds permits, some permit have one skill_course, and some permit have several skill_courses, I need to exact matching all, not just one permit as pk=1.....