# Django many-to-many query matching all related fields

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-select-related

I have two models connected by a many-to-many relationship in django.

```py
class BuildingMapping(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=False)
    buildings = models.ManyToManyField(
        Building, related_name="mapping"
    )

class Building(models.Model):
    function = models.CharField(
        max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True
    )
```

Function is a string containing one or more identifier divieded by a "/" e. g. "1300", "1300/2200", "1300/2230/7500", ...

I now want to perform a query that gets only `BuildingMapping` instances where the function for **all** Buildings is identical. I tried the following, but this will also return `BuildingMapping` instances where only one Building has "1300" as function.

```py
BuildingMapping.objects.filter(buildings__function="1300")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django filter queryset \_\_in for \*every\* item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct, you want to get function field contains "1300". If it is right:
`BuildingMapping.objects.filter(buildings__function__contains="1300")`

Comment: What I understood is he wants to get the `BuildingMapping` which has *all* the required `Building`-instances from a list of ids.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to fetch all the results which are matching 1300. What you are doing is exact match

[image]**strong text**

You need to use icontains(case insensitive) or contains(case sensitive) for getting all matched data

[image][image]