# Django filter queryset __in for items only in list

Tags: django-queryset, django-filter

Models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Post(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Data:

```
a_post=Post.objects.create(title='a')
ab_post=Post.objects.create(title='ab')
ac_post=Post.objects.create(title='ac')
a_tag=a_post.tags.create(name='a')
ab_post.tags.add(a_tag)
b_tag=ab_post.tags.create(name='b')
ac_post.tags.add(a_tag)
ac_post=ac_post.tags.create(name='c')
```

I want to query all Posts with only tags in list. Posts with other tags should not be returned.
Code like this:

```
Post.objects.filter(tags__name__only_in=['a','b']).all()
```

should return [a_post, ab_post].

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list). Chained filters will not help. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the number of `Tag`s that satisfy the predicate is the same as the total number of tags:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Post.objects.annotate(
    ntags=Count('tags')
).filter(
    ntags=Count('tags', filter=Q(tags__name__in=['a', 'b'])),
    ntags__gt=0
)
```

The first filter thus checks if the total number of related tags is the same as the number of tags with as name `'a'` or `'b'`. If the number is different, then we know that there is a tag with a different name.

The second filter checks if the number of tags is greater than zero, to exclude matches with no tags at all.