# get first object from every type in Django query

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a query like this:

```py
objs = MyModel.objects.filter(type__in=[1,2,3,4]).order_by('-created_at')
```

is there a way to fetch only the first item of every type and not all the items with these types by adding a condition to this query?

Comment: The question was not clear. If you need to get the first or last item use .first() or .last() method at the end of the query.

Comment: @SivaSankar as you see I'm filtering the types in the query I want the first item of each type sorted by `-created_at` field

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list

Comment: What database do you use? Can you share the `MyModel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a manual way.

```
type_list = [1,2,3,4]
new_list = []

for each_type in type_list:
    latest_obj = MyModel.objects.filter(type=each_type).order_by('-created_at').first()
    new_list.append(latest_obj)
```

This new_list contains the latest object or each type.

Or

```
objs = MyModel.objects.filter(type__in=[1,2,3,4]).order_by('type', '-created_at').distinct('type')
```

Reference: [Django distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Comment: yeah, I'm well aware of this manual way but I'm looking for a way to fetch all the data I want in one query

Comment: Edited the answer. Try this query

Comment: Note that this will only work on postgres, as other db backends do not support distinct on fields:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct