# Get first Item in a django orm query for each unique value of a column

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a table of Snapshots. It has the following attributes:

- device_ip
- created_at
- name

There are multiple records in the table. Various records can have the same device_ip but will have unique names.

I want to fetch the latest record for each device_ip ordered by created_at. I am using MySQL database.

Here is what I tried:

```
Snapshot.objects.filter(device_ip__in=device_ip_list)
    .order_by("-created_at")
    .values(
        "device_ip", "name", "created_at"
    ).first()
```

But It provides the last record of the table. Suggestions?

Comment: with same ordering you could try to get the last so Snapshot.objects.filter(device_ip__in=device_ip_list)
    .order_by("-created_at")
    .values(
        "device_ip", "name", "created_at"
    ).last()

Comment: @Mojtaba I want to last record for each IP in device_ip_list. But I am getting a single record.

Comment: could you add what you expect to be the end result ? ( an example of Snapshot object before and after query.)

Comment: last record means its providing latest one isnt it what you want?

Comment: @HemalPatel I want latest record of each device IP in the table.

Comment: Answered at page: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892330/get-first-object-from-every-type-in-django-query

Answer (score 0):

You should use distinct function on the unique field (which is "name" in this case).
So your query can be like below:

```
Snapshot.objects.order_by("-created_at").distinct("name")
```

or

```
Snapshot.objects.order_by("name", "-created_at").distinct("name")
```

- Note that if you use `first()` on a query, It will return only the first object of the query-set.

Comment: I think we can't use distinct in MYSQL. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @SmrutiSahoo I assume all the SQL DBMS have distinct clause. Have you tried it ?