# Django first() for every item

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have a model `EventParticipant`, which stores participant data for a given `Event`.
Now I want to retrieve the *next* event participance for a list of users.

The following:

`EventParticipance.objects.filter(user__in=userlist, start__gte=timezone.now()).order_by(start)` would give me all event participances for all users in `userlist` that start in the future. However, I only want the first one for each user.

In Postgres, this could be achieved (I think) by this:

`EventParticipance.objects.filter(user__in=userlist, start__gte=timezone.now()).order_by(start).distinct('user')`.

However, this does not work for sqlite or mysql.

Obviously, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892330/get-first-object-from-every-type-in-django-query), this would work, but I suppose it'd be very slow:

```
next_occurrence_ids = []
for user in userlist:
   id = EventParticipant.objects.filter(user=user, .....).order_by(start).values('id').first()
   next_occurrence_ids.append(id)
return EventParticipant.objects.filter(id__in=next_occurrence_ids
```

Is there any other strategy I could employ?

Comment: I still don’t understand why neither .first() nor .last() worked for you.

Comment: Because I would need a `first()` for every user in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :)

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Subquery

event_participances = (
    EventParticipance.objects.filter(
        start__gte=timezone.now(),
        user=OuterRef("pk")
    ).order_by("start")
)    
# Assuming userlist variable is queryset:

next_occurrence_ids = (
    userlist.filter(Exists(event_participances)).annotate(
        first_participance=Subquery(event_participances.values("pk")[:1])
    ).values_list("first_participance", flat=True)
)
return EventParticipance.objects.filter(id__in=next_occurrence_ids)
```