# Multiple filters in django

Tags: python, django

I want to filter movies, that fit only to selected genres, for example:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    if 'genres' in self.request.GET:
        queryset = queryset.filter(genre__in=self.request.GET.getlist('genres'))
    return queryset
```

This filter shows movies that fit into at least one to filter, but I want to show movies that are fit all of the selected genress like 'comedy, horror, fantasy' and all of the selected genres must be in the movie genres
How cat I do this?

Models:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField('Description')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=100)
    tagline = models.CharField('Tagline', max_length=200, default='')
    description = models.TextField('Description')
    poster = models.ImageField('Poster', upload_to='movies/')
    country = models.CharField('Country', max_length=50)
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(
        Actor, verbose_name='actors', related_name='film_actor'
    )
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(
        Genre, verbose_name='genres', related_name='genres'
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        verbose_name='category',
        related_name='category',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your Movie and Genre models? From your code, it looks like Movie has FK to Genre, which is 1-n relation and therefore movie cannot have multiple genres.

Comment: added models to post

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a quick fix i believe this has already been answered quite well here:
[Django filter queryset __in for *every* item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list)

In short, if you have a small set of genres (up to around 5) then you may add `.filter()` for each genre:

```
Movie.objects.filter(genre='genre1').filter(genre='genre2')....
```

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Comment: yeah, thats what I've been looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're looking for this?

```
genre = ['horror', 'comedy'] (dummy list of genre)
queryset = queryset.objects.filter(genre__in=genre)
```

Comment: i have form with checkboxes where user can select genres and it filters movies by user's selected genres,  it works ok, but if user selected 'fantasy' and 'horror' it will show all fantasies and all horros, but i want to show movies that are both horror and fantasy

Comment: can you share relevant record from database which you want to achieve? i wanna see how it stored with two tags