# Django Filter row by ManyToManyField so that all m2m are a sublist of a list

Tags: django

I have a django model `Books` with a manytomany field `authors`

If the books contain

- `Good Omens` with authors [`Neil Gaiman`, `Terry Pratchett`]
- `American Gods` with author [`Neil Gaiman`]
- `Heads You Lose` with authors [`Lisa Lutz`, `David Hayward`]
- `The Passenger` with author [`Lisa Lutz`]

How can I return the books that contain a substring of a bigger list.

So the big list of [`Neil Gaiman`, `Terry Pratchett`, `Lisa Lutz`] will give me [`Good Omens`, `American Gods`, `The Passenger`] and not `Heads you Lose` (since `David Hayward` is not part of the big list)

I've seen this [Django filter queryset __in for *every* item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list/8637972#8637972). But I only want to also return objects that are a substring.

Answer (score -1):

```
authors = ['Neil Gaiman', 'Terry Pratchett', 'Lisa Lutz']

query = Q()
for author in authors:
    query |= Q(authors__name__icontains=author)

books = Book.objects.filter(query).distinct()
```

This should do what I understood from your question.

Update. Since OP asks to return books only when all authors are in the big list.

```
def get_books_with_authors_in_list(author_names):
    q_objects = Q()
    for author_name in author_names:
        q_objects |= Q(authors__name__icontains=author_name)

    annotated_books = Book.objects.annotate(num_authors=Count('authors'))

    filtered_books = annotated_books.filter(q_objects, num_authors=len(author_names))

    return filtered_books

author_names = ['Neil Gaiman', 'Terry Pratchett', 'Lisa Lutz']
matching_books = get_books_with_authors_in_list(author_names)
```

This way only books that have all their authors in the big list will be returned.

Comment: This will actually return `Heads You Lose` since it has an author of [`Lisa Lutz`, `David Hayward`] but `David Hayward` is not part of the list `authors`.

Comment: Isnt this the intended result ?

Comment: No.

"So the big list of [Neil Gaiman, Terry Pratchett, Lisa Lutz] will give me [Good Omens, American Gods, The Passenger] and not Heads you Lose (since David Hayward is not part of the big list)"

Comment: Check my updated version.